# Database String Selection

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have passed a name to my data base, through which I want to extract the details of that name. I am trying to do this . How do I solve it??  " name " is the name clicked. I want to use this parameter to query the database and get related information for this name.

```
public String getName(String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String namereturned = "";
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
            KEY_PERSONALPHONE, KEY_HOMEPHONE, KEY_OFFICEPHONE };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "="
            + name +"'", null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
            return  namereturned = c.getString(1);


    }
    return null;
}
```

LOG CAT

```
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.contactlist/com.example.contactlist.ViewContact}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "'" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, Name, Personalnumber, Homenumber, Officenumber FROM ContactList WHERE Name=nishanth'
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "'" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, Name, Personalnumber, Homenumber, Officenumber FROM ContactList WHERE Name=nishanth'
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at com.example.contactlist.DBContact.getName(DBContact.java:138)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at com.example.contactlist.ViewContact.onCreate(ViewContact.java:31)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-04 15:15:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the query as

```
 Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "='"
            + name +"'", null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: In what way does it now not work?  Has the error message changed?  The original error stated that it thought that 'nishanth' was a column, as the value was not wrapped in single quotes.  As such I would have expected the answer of @rshetty to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

See the line:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: nishanth (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, Name, Personalnumber, Homenumber, Officenumber FROM ContactList WHERE Name=nishanth
```

It means that the one or more of these columns do not exist in the table. You might have spelled them incorrectly in the database table or the query. Check these out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stack trace the query you are running is;

```
SELECT _id, Name, Personalnumber, Homenumber, Officenumber 
FROM ContactList 
WHERE Name = nishanth
```

As Rajeev says the addition of single quote (or even double quotes) is required around the where statement for example.

```
SELECT _id, Name, Personalnumber, Homenumber, Officenumber 
FROM ContactList 
WHERE Name = 'nishanth'
```

or

```
SELECT _id, Name, Personalnumber, Homenumber, Officenumber 
FROM ContactList 
WHERE Name = "nishanth"
```

I ran a similar query directly on my SQLite database (see http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html section "9. Accessing SQLite databases directly" and don't forget to donate ;-) ) and it returned results for both single and double quotes.

If quotes are removed the same error message is generate that you have ie.

> Error: no such column:ABC123

where ABC123 was used as a constraint.

IMHO. If you test your SQL against the database, outside of Eclipse or whatever IDE or programming language you are using, at least you know your SQL syntax is correct. Work back through the calling code to identify the problem.

As you are using the "=" this is very specific and will not match if the text case changes eg. "nishanth" and ="Nishanth" are completely different.

This is a trap .......

I prefer to change user input to either upper case ("NISHANTH") or lower case ("nishanth") before inserting data into database. This way if you retrieve values from your database and subsequently use it as a constraint you know it would match.

If you want to be really fancy create a class to parse string values from, for example, sentence case to upper case prior to inserting into database and perform the reverse when displaying values on screen.

Trust this explanation is of some use. Good luck.